# The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: PUT. LARAVEL

Tags: laravel

I would like to send data with PUT method
However, this error happens.

Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException
The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: PUT.

I don't really understand why my code is not correct.

web.php

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return redirect('/home');
});

Auth::routes();
Route::put('/save_data', 'AbcController@saveData')->name('save_data');
```

view.blade.php

```
        <form action="{{route('save_data')}}" method="POST">
          @method('PUT')
          @csrf
          <input type = "hidden" name = "type" value ='stack' >
         
          <div>
            <button>post</button>
          </div>
        </form>
```

when it is changed

```
          <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
          <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

instead of

```
          @method('PUT')
          @csrf
```

It works well.

Comment: Hello, just some clarifying questions. Is it possible that this form lies within another form (nested)? Could there be another defined route for `/save_data` that uses `post`?

Comment: @flow-stack please list routes that related to the save data route inside it's group or related at least.

Comment: Can you verify what's the rendered HTML when you uses the directives `@method` and `@csrf`?

Answer (score 0):

make sure to check First Another Route with Same Name
You can make POST route and dont need to put this after form tag @method('PUT')

CHange the Placement of the route before this Auth::routes();

use save_data in route instead of /save_data.

use {{url('save_data')}} in action instead of {{route('save_data')}}.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
<button>post</button>
```

to:

```
<button type="submit">post</button>
```

Comment: By default, a button without type will be `submit`. I would recommend to specify the type for clarity but this is not mandatory in this context.

Answer (score 0):

> If you insist on using PUT you can change the form action to POST and
> add a hidden method_field that has a value PUTand a hidden csrf field
> (if you are using blade then you just need to add @csrf_field and {{
> method_field('PUT') }}). This way the form would accept the request.
> You can simply change the route and form method to POST. It will work
> just fine since you are the one defining the route and not using the
> resource group

after all this run artisan command

```
php artisan route:clear
```